# date creation with Image::Exiftools or Date::Handler

Tags: date, perl

I'm trying to merge all dirs containing pictures having different timeZone, in a single dir, uniform file's names with a same format (Hungarian style yyyymmdd_hhmmss) eliminating huge of duplicates, at once.

I was looking for modules (over the stat statement which return only the epoch (stat(file))[9]) that can read the file's creation date, not the last modification or access date.
I fount Immage::ExifTools seem to be the effective and easiest to list.

I noted that after several cycling into the dir the module stop to extract the correct date/time output stuck in a monotone identical wrong date/time value for the next over files. Here is the list and below one of pictures that get me into this trouble: more precisely file's property on win10 give a creation date of 20140626 12:16 pm; running instead the routine I obtain 20021208_120000.

```
foreach $img(@img){
    next if -l $img;
    $img =~ /.+(\..+$)/;
    $ext = $1;
#   %ENV;
    
    $exif=new Image::ExifTool;
    $exif->ExtractInfo($dir.$img);
    $for = $exif->GetValue('CreateDate');
    $for =~ s/$space/\_/g;
    $for =~ s/\://g;
    $for = '_'.$for; 
    
    $size = (stat($dir.$img))[7];
    
#   $date = Date->new($date[9]);
#   @data = $date->array;

#tie my %date, 'Date::Tie', utc_epoch => $date{$date[9]}; #tz => $date{tz};
#my $date = Date::Tie->new( epoch => $date[9] );
%date;  

#   $for = IMG.$for.$ext;
    if (!$all{'IMG'.$for.$ext}){
        $all{'IMG'.$for.$ext}= $size ;
        rename $dir.$img, $dir.'IMG'.$for.$ext;
        print "rename $dir.$img, $dir.'IMG'.$for.$ext\n";
    }elsif($all{'IMG'.$for.$ext} == $size){
        unlink $dir.$img;
        print "Deleting $dir.$img\n";
}
```

Checking the files properties involved, the "wrong" ones seems to have the same properties "working" ones: both working and wrong state the properties of : creation/acquisition date, modification date and last access date..

I can't understand where the module fault.

Have you any recommendation ? Any different module to use ?

Thanks
Simon
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a complete runnable example, see [mcve] for more information

Comment: *"I noted that after several cycling into the dir the module stop to extract the correct date/time output"* Can you upload the problematic files somewhere? Then we can try to reproduce the behavior

Comment: I am not able to obtain the create date from the image you included. Can you try [this](https://pastebin.com/YCrQWf7K) test script?

Comment: On linux, I am not able to update the `FileCreateDate` either. [Here](https://pastebin.com/Jx3tt9Y5) is my test script, it gives error: *"This tag is Windows/Mac only in File:FileCreateDate (ValueConvInv)"* Are you on Windows or Mac?

Comment: Thanks Hakon, I work in win 10 OS, PerlBuilder 2 and Activeperl 5.xx I guess. I've tryed to copy & paste your 2 scripts, but what represent the 2 jpg you mentioned , specifically 1 and 2 ? If those two are my jpg, I can tell you that the first script return same result as mine. Your second script step over the statement if (exists $info->{Error}) {
    die "Could not extract meta information from '$fn': $info->{Error}";
}
say "Warning: $info->{Warning}" if exists $info->{Warning}; without any allert nor error

Comment: Yes I think `FileCreateDate` will not work on Linux, but it should work on Windows as far as I understand. I will try later on a Windows machine, which hopefully will give us some more information.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use [Win32API::File::Time](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32API::File::Time) to read and modify the file creation time:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32API::File::Time qw(GetFileTime SetFileTime);
use File::Temp qw(tempdir);

my $dir = tempdir( CLEANUP => 1 );
my $fn = 'test.txt';
open (my $fh, '>', $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
say $fh "Foobar";
close $fh;
print_file_times($fn);
my ($atime, $mtime, $ctime) = GetFileTime ($fn);
SetFileTime ($fn, undef, undef, $ctime-180);
print_file_times($fn);

sub print_file_times {
    my ($fn) = @_;
    my ($atime, $mtime, $ctime) = GetFileTime ($fn);
    say "File: $fn:";
    say "  File access time: $atime";
    say "  File modification time: $mtime";
    say "  File creation time: $ctime";
    return $ctime;
}
```

**Output**:

```
File: test.txt:
  File access time: 1614640101
  File modification time: 1614640101
  File creation time: 1614639958
File: test.txt:
  File access time: 1614640101
  File modification time: 1614640101
  File creation time: 1614639778
```

Comment: thnks I'll check

Comment: unfortunately its works fine, but the $ctime is not the real acquisition date of the picture but is date of when the file were transferred to the pc...